# Query a mysql DATETIME with a given timezone in Java

Tags: java, mysql, date

I am trying to query a mysql DATETIME from Java.  I know the the time zone of the server, but I cannot pull the datetime out with the time zone as I would expect.

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(...);

Date d1=rs.getTime(i, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));
Date d2=rs.getTime(i, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST")));

System.out.println("d1: "+d1.getTime());
System.out.println("d2: "+d2.getTime());
```

This leaves me with:

```
d1: 40258000
d2: 40258000
```

Am I missing something basic here?

`ResultSet.getDate()` does take the Calendar into account. But I cant use it because it truncates the time info.  It's still strange `ResultSet.getTime()` wouldn't handle any timezone conversions.

Comment: Are you aware that `Date.getTime()` always shows in GMT?

Comment: ResultSet.getTime() or Date.getTime()?  I know Date.getTime() gets pulled in UTC.

Comment: @user833970 Well, as Jon Skeet pointed out, ResultSet.getTime() does in fact take the timezone into account (according to the docs) if the database does not store timezone information. My guess is that your database does store said information, because clearly it did not take the calendar into account in your example :/

Comment: Then why would it be taking the calendar into account on the ResultSet.getDate()?  I think this may be a bug with the connector (I am using mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar).

Comment: My horrible final solution was to change the system timezone to mach the mysql server timezone.  god have mercy on us all.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTime%28int,%20java.util.Calendar%29) states:

> This method uses the given calendar to construct an appropriate millisecond value for the time if the underlying database does not store timezone information.

So perhaps the database *does* store time zone information in this case?

What does your value in the database look like, and what is it supposed to represent?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be letting the MySQL server convert the time zone:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(timefield,'PST','UTC') AS tf
```

for example would convert the `DATETIME` value in the field `timefield` from PST to UTC time (and then returning it as `tf`).

Answer (score -1):

getTime on the Date class returns the epoch time according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html
so it would adjust out your timezone. I think that page implies you should use the timezone adjusted calendar to get your local time.